# flutter multipart force content type

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

I try send image as `Multipart file` and add to header `mime` type: `image/jpeg`

But if I look into http request, I see that `contentType` is: `Multipart/form-data;boundary....` not `image/jpeg`

This is screenshot from `DartDevTools` with information about failure request:
[image]

This is my code where I force content type:

```dart
 Future<Response> postMultimedia(MultimediaMetadata mm) async {
    log("[MEDIA] start send: ${mm.localPath.toString()}");
    print(MyMethods.getMediaTypeBasedOnExtension(mm.localPath)!.mimeType);
    String uriString =
        "$homeUrl/upload/${mm.multimediaType.collectionSubPath}/${mm.idVisit}";
    urlLog(uriString);
    final body = FormData({
      'file': MultipartFile(mm.localPath, filename: 'avatar.png'),
    });
    final response = await post(uriString, body,
        contentType:
            MyMethods.getMediaTypeBasedOnExtension(mm.localPath)!.mimeType, // this methods return string: "image/jpeg"
        headers: {
          "token": RuntimeMetadata.getTokenNoNull(),
        });
    return response;
  }
```

I send requests to backend which accept only request where header content type is image so I must force `image/jpeg`

There is any way to send this file as image, not multipart?

Answer (score 0):

You should define content-type as below:

```
MultipartFile(mm.localPath, filename: 'avatar.png' contentType:MediaType('image','jpeg'))
```